# Database update with Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, xampp

I'm hosting a MariaDB DB using xampp, with default options.

I've installed `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `EntityFrameworkCore`.

This is my Web API's `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using USP_Server;
using USP_Server.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddDbContext<GameDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")));


builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
{
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, MockUserService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

GameDbContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SharedLibrary;

namespace USP_Server;

public class GameDbContext: DbContext
{
    public GameDbContext(DbContextOptions<GameDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

`appsettings.development.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Db": "server=localhost,3306;User ID=root;password=;Database=unitybackendtest;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

I've deployed a migration with:

```
~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add Initial
```

but when I try to commit the db with:

```
~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef database update
```

I get an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

I've checked a lot of things, like versions, server path. ports...
restarting the PC, xampp, VS

I just want to push the DB

Comment: MariaDb is not SqlServer. You need to use MySql server bits. Look at https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/using-mysql-mariadb-in-entity-framework-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to connect to a MariaDB server using the SQL Server provider.

To resolve the issue, you need to make a few changes:

1. **Update the provider** in your `AddDbContext` method from `UseSqlServer` to `UseMySql`. This change will ensure that Entity Framework Core uses the MySQL/MariaDB provider instead of the SQL Server provider.

   ```
   builder.Services.AddDbContext<GameDbContext>(o =>
        o.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")));
   ```
2. **Ensure** that you have the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` NuGet package installed in your project. This package provides the MySQL/MariaDB provider for Entity Framework Core.
3. **Update** the `appsettings.development.json` file to include the correct connection string for MariaDB. The format of the connection string should match the one used for connecting to MariaDB

   ```
   {
       "ConnectionStrings": {
           "Db": "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=unitybackendtest;"
        },
        "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
               "Default": "Information",
               "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
            }
        }
    }
   ```

**Ensure** that the `server`, `port`, `username`, `password`, and `database name` in the connection string match your MariaDB configuration.

After this regenerate the migration.

Comment: builder.Services.AddDbContext<GameDbContext>(o => o.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"),ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"))));

, UseMySql had to know the db version